# covariance of a transformed Gaussian matrix

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, linear-transformations

Suppose $X \in R^{m \times n}$ is a matrix with each entry being an i.i.d Gaussian random variable with 0 mean and unit variance. Suppose $A,B$ are known matrices of appropriate dimensions. What is the distribution of $Y = AXB$ ?

Specifically, we know that if $x \sim N(0,\Sigma)$ was a Gaussian random vector, then 
$Ax \sim N(0,A \Sigma A^T)$. Does something like this hold for matrices as well?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that

$$\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} = (x_1,...,x_m)^T$$

where $x_i \sim N(0, \sigma_i^2)$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is

$$ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}  = \left(
\begin {array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1m}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nm}\\
\end{array}
 \right) $$

Then

$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \left(
\begin {array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1m}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nm}\\
\end{array}
 \right)
\left(
\begin {array}{c}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
\vdots\\
x_{m}\\
\end{array}
 \right)
 $$

$$ = (a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1m}x_m,\cdots,a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+\cdots+a_{nm}x_m)^T $$

$$ = (\sum_{k=1}^ma_{1k}x_k,\cdots,\sum_{k=1}^ma_{nk}x_k)^T $$

So each component is a linear combination of normal random variables. The linear combination of $m$ normal random variables such as

$$ c_i = \sum_{k=1}^ma_{ik}x_k$$

where $x_i \sim N(0, \sigma_i^2)$ is a normal distribution with

$$c_i \sim N(0, \sum_{k=1}^ma_{ik}^2\sigma^2_k)$$

That is if you define $\Sigma$ as

$$ \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}  = \left(
\begin {array}{cccc}
\sigma^2_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \sigma^2_{2} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \sigma^2_{m}\\
\end{array}
 \right) $$

Then $\mathbf{Ax} \sim N(0, \mathbf{A}\Sigma\mathbf{A}^T)$

Comment: Yes, if $x$ is a vector then this holds. What happens when $x$ is a matrix and you multiply both the left and right side?